# for loop resets construct inputs

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, constructor

for the following code:

```
System.out.println("How many types of food do the gerbils eat?");       
    int F = keyboard.nextInt();
    food = new food[F];

    for
        (int a = 0; a<F; a++){
        System.out.println("Name of food number " + (a+1));
        foodname = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Max amount of food " + (a+1));
        maximum = keyboard.nextInt();

        food[a] = new food(foodname, maximum);
        for (int n = 0; n<F; n++){
        System.out.println(food[n]);
        }
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
How many types of food do the gerbils eat?
2
Name of food number 1
p
Max amount of food 1
5
p 5
null
Name of food number 2
r
Max amount of food 2
5
r 5
r 5
```

As you can see, every time the loop restarts, the new input values for food name and food maximum are reset. why is it doing that, and how do i fix it so that it stores my original input for food 1 name and maximum?

Class food:

```
public class food {

public static String foodname;
public static int maximum;


public food(String foodname, int maximum) {
this.foodname = foodname;
this.maximum = maximum;
}

public String getFood(){
return foodname;
}

public int getmaxamount(){
return maximum;
}

public String toString() {
return (this.getFood() + " " + this.getmaxamount());
}
}
```

Comment: What the keyword static means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Food class, you declared

```
foodname
maximum
```

as `static`.
It means, those values will be the same for every Food you create.

As you want different kind of Food, simply remove those modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has already been answered, I thought I'd go ahead and add this:

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects. This is accomplished with the `static` modifier. Fields that have the `static` modifier in their declaration are called *static fields* or *class variables*. They are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory.

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html